# Why dont buttons show up in the grid when I create them using a for loop in C# WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, button, grid, project

Trying to make a board for a Connect 4 game using buttons however after creating a method to create the actual board itself by creating buttons for each individual cell in the grid,nothing shows up.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private readonly int[,] _board;
        private readonly int _height;
        private readonly bool _isComp;
        private readonly Brush _p1Color;
        private readonly string _p1Name;
        private readonly Ellipse _p1Sym;
        private readonly int _width;
        private readonly int _win;
        private Ellipse mycircle;
        private bool _isFalling;
        private bool turnPlayer1;
        private int _turns;
        private string _winner;
        public string Mode;
        public int[,] BoardArray = new int[5, 6];
            
        public MainWindow()
        {

        }

        public MainWindow (int row, int column , int win, Ellipse newP1, Ellipse newP2, Brush p1Color, Brush p2Color,
        string p1Name, string p2Name, bool isComp, int time, string mode, Brush back, Uri music)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            turnPlayer1 = true;
            for (int loopColumn = 0; loopColumn <= 6; loopColumn++)
            {
                for (int loopRow = 0; loopRow <= 5; loopColumn++)
                {
                    BoardArray[loopRow, loopColumn] = 0;
                }
            }
            row = 6;
            column = 7;
            CreateBoard(column, row);
            mycircle  = newP1;
            _p1Color = p1Color;
            _p1Name = p1Name;
            _win = win;
            _winner = "";
            _isComp = isComp;
            Mode = mode;
        }

        private void buttonClicked(Button btn)
        {
            var rowDef = Grid.GetRow(btn);
            var columnDef = Grid.GetColumn(btn);
            var col = columnDef;
            DropCounter(col);
        }

        private int EmptyRow(int column)
        {
            for(int row = 6-1;row >=0;row-- )
            {
                var arrayRow = row; ;
                var arrayCol = column;
                if(BoardArray[row,column]== 0)
                {
                    return row;
                }
            }

            return -1;
        }
        private void DropCounter(int column)
        {
            var freeRow = EmptyRow(column);
            if (freeRow == -1) return;

            mycircle = new Ellipse();
            mycircle.Stroke = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Black;
            mycircle.Fill = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.DarkBlue;
            mycircle.Height = 100;
            mycircle.Width = 100;
       
            Grid.SetColumn(mycircle, 1);
            Grid.SetRow(mycircle, 1);
            myGrid.Children.Insert(0,mycircle);
        }


        private void Btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (sender is Button btn && EmptyRow(Grid.GetColumn(btn)) != -1) buttonClicked(btn);
        }

        private void CreateBoard(int column,int rows)
        {
            for (var row = 0; row < rows; row++)
            {
                for (var col = 0; col < column; column++)
                {
                    Button button = new Button();
                    {
                        var brush = new ImageBrush();
                        brush.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("gridsingle.png.bmp", UriKind.Relative));
                        button.Background = brush;
                        Name = "btn_" + row + "_" + column;

                    };
                    button.Click += Btn_Click;
                    Grid.SetRow(button, row);
                    Grid.SetColumn(button, column);
                    myGrid.Children.Add(button);
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Apologies for the messy code,this is a HW assignment for highschool and programming isnt my favourite part of the course

Not really sure whats the main cause as I am implementing the same code as my friend yet his buttons all load on his window.

Comment: When you use `Grid.SetColumn` you are passing `column`, but should be using `col`. Also you are incrementing `column` in the for loop:  `.. col < column; column++)` change that to `col` as well.  Naming variables descriptively is important to help avoid these kinds of mistakes.  Use something like `columnCount` and `rowCount` for those function parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I'll be honest, there are actually a whole lot of things wrong with this. Normally I'd recommend throwing it out and starting again, but I'm guessing time is a factor, so I'll do my best to help.

First of all, this doesn't look right:

```
public MainWindow()
{
}

public MainWindow(int row, int column, int win, Ellipse newP1, Ellipse newP2, Brush p1Color, Brush p2Color, string p1Name, string p2Name, bool isComp, int time, string mode, Brush back, Uri music)
{
```

Ordinarily, the first constructor is the one that gets called, and since your implementation is empty, it explains why you aren't seeing anything. Looking at your code, the parameters being passed into your second constructor aren't actually being used, so get rid of both constructors and just keep the logic needed to initialize your board:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    turnPlayer1 = true;
    for (int loopColumn = 0; loopColumn <= 6; loopColumn++)
    {
        for (int loopRow = 0; loopRow <= 5; loopRow++)
        {
            BoardArray[loopRow, loopColumn] = 0;
        }
    }
    var row = 6;
    var column = 7;
    CreateBoard(column, row);
    _winner = "";
}
```

You'll notice there was a bug in your original code which I've fixed:

```
for (int loopColumn = 0; loopColumn <= 6; loopColumn++)
{
    for (int loopRow = 0; loopRow <= 5; loopColumn++)
```

That second loop should be incrementing loopRow, not loopColumn. (As a side note, you've hard-coded these loops to 6 columns, and 5 rows, they should instead be using the values in the column and row variables).

Next, there's a bug in your CreateBoard function:

```
private void CreateBoard(int column, int rows)
{
    for (var row = 0; row < rows; row++)
    {
        for (var col = 0; col < column; column++)
```

The column variable is storing the total number of columns, so you should be doing col++, not column++. Similarly, when you set the Grid column for the button, you should be setting it to col, not column:

```
button.Click += Btn_Click;
Grid.SetRow(button, row);
Grid.SetColumn(button, column);  // <---- this is wrong
myGrid.Children.Add(button);
```

The code in your DropCounter function also has problems:

```
Grid.SetColumn(mycircle, 1);
Grid.SetRow(mycircle, 1);
myGrid.Children.Insert(0, mycircle);
```

Notice you're always setting the column and row to 1, you should be setting them to column and freeRow.

Last of all, you're never updating BoardArray to make note of the fact that tokens are being dropped, so you'll just keep dropping them on the bottom row. You need to update it at the end of your DropCounter function so that your EmptyRow function works correctly:

```
BoardArray[freeRow, column] = 1;
```